# Should I offload to a database or do data transformations directly in Java?

Tags: java, database

I'm pretty new with Java and I'm getting a handle on the objects, arrays, and maps.  What I've done so far is tap into a database to grab a bunch of information about accounts.  Now what I want to do is simply do a count, but region, of each sales rep's accounts.  In SQL this is a very simple GROUP BY COUNT type query.

So I actually took my data, threw it into a table on the database, then retrieved the query!  Works great!  But I wonder if this is bad practice?  Or maybe it's the right thing to do?

Before doing this I was about to figure out a way to "pivot" my data so that it would count each account per name and then build a table that way.  Seems ugly.  I managed to do it with a `HashMap<String, Integer>`, where String is the Rep Name and Integer is the count... but all the sudden I need to do a further breakdown of the postal code, so now I'm suddenly messing around with a 2D `HashMap<RepName, HashMap<PostalCode, Count>>`, which seems like a nuisance to handle.  Never mind the question of what happens when I need to further break it down, perhaps by Industry (How many Manufacturers are in that postal code for that rep??  Oh no!).

That being said, am I doing the right thing?  Seems to be the most flexible approach.   I just worry that there's some cons to do things this way.. probably sacrificing some speed, and perhaps stability if somehow the database connection breaks?

Please don't think of this as an "opinion" type question, I'm sure there's actually a PROPER process for this type of question.  I also realize different circumstances might yield a different answer, so please outline what qualifies which technique.

Comment: I believe it's a good idea to *outsource* data selection and/or aggregation to database engines.

Comment: If your data has to be persisted, then by all means use a database and its querying features. If not, then the usual technique, especially if the data is small, is to use algorithms, methods and data structures. The Java 8 stream API is great for those kinds of operations on collections.

Comment: Well I will eventually want to "save" my scenarios (it's going to be a territory engine) so persistence will matter eventually.  I'm actually considering making an object that will take in a 2d Object Array, and a sql string, and then output the transformed data.  To do this I will have a temp table that is created, the original object dumped into, the sql query then performed, the result translated into the return object, and then the temp table 'dropped'.  Good idea?

Comment: this is about as **off-topic: opinion based** and **too broad** as it gets!

Comment: This is about as opinion based as "should I use insertion sort or bottom-up heap sort?". Sure, you can have an opinion, but there is also a true answer for it, depending on the usage scenario. I like this kind of questions way better than stuff you can look up in an API reference.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in a database, let the database do the processing. If it is already in memory, it is probably faster to process it there. Still, to get hard data, you could try and run a performance test of each scenario with a realistic number of records.